# mvn test doesnt work with Apache Poi

Tags: java, apache, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, apache-poi

**mvn test doesnt work with Apache Poi.**

1. If i exclude the code associated to Apache POI within my Framework: **mvn test works.**
2. However my code needs to access specific data from an Excel sheet and therefore i need to use 'mvn test' and Apache POI together.
3. Seem to be getting the following exception when using mvn test:
   [image]
4. For example if i comment the following code 'examples' mvn test successfully executed my test cases:
   [image]

[image]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>uk.co.uat.pizzahut</groupId>
<artifactId>PhFramework</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>PhFramework</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15-beta2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.danielflower.apprunner</groupId>
        <artifactId>app-runner</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>20.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
```

Excel reader code:

```
private XSSFSheet sheet = null;
private XSSFRow row = null;
private XSSFCell cell = null;
String path = null;


public ExcelReader() throws IOException {
    path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\main\\java\\PhFramework\\testData\\pricebandPrices.xlsx";
    fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);


    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
}


public int getSheetRows() throws IOException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\gpb7642\\Desktop\\PhAutomationFramework\\PhFramework\\src\\main\\java\\PhFramework\\testData\\Setup.properties");
    p.load(fi);
    int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(p.getProperty("priceband"));
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
    return (sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1);
}


public int getSheetColumns(String sheetName) throws IOException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\gpb7642\\Desktop\\PhAutomationFramework\\PhFramework\\src\\main\\java\\PhFramework\\testData\\Setup.properties");
    p.load(fi);
    int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(p.getProperty("priceband"));
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
    row = sheet.getRow(0);
    return (row.getLastCellNum());
}


public String getCellDataString(int colNum, int rowNum) throws IOException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\gpb7642\\Desktop\\PhAutomationFramework\\PhFramework\\src\\main\\java\\PhFramework\\testData\\Setup.properties");
    p.load(fi);
    int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(p.getProperty("priceband"));
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
    row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
    cell = row.getCell(colNum);
    return (cell.getStringCellValue());
}

public double getCellDataDouble(int colNum, int rowNum) throws IOException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\gpb7642\\Desktop\\PhAutomationFramework\\PhFramework\\src\\main\\java\\PhFramework\\testData\\Setup.properties");
    p.load(fi);
    int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(p.getProperty("priceband"));
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
    row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
    cell = row.getCell(colNum);
    return (cell.getNumericCellValue());
}

public String getCellDataText(String colName, int rowNum) throws IOException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\gpb7642\\Desktop\\PhAutomationFramework\\PhFramework\\src\\main\\java\\PhFramework\\testData\\Setup.properties");
    p.load(fi);
    int colNum = -1;
    int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(p.getProperty("priceband"));
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
    for (int i = 0; i < getSheetColumns(p.getProperty("priceband")); i++) {
        row = sheet.getRow(0);
        cell = row.getCell(i);
        if (cell.getStringCellValue().equals(colName)) {
            colNum = cell.getColumnIndex();
            break;
        }
    }
    row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
    cell = row.getCell(colNum);
    return (cell.getStringCellValue());
}

public double getCellDataNumber(String colName, int rowNum) throws IOException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\gpb7642\\Desktop\\PhAutomationFramework\\PhFramework\\src\\main\\java\\PhFramework\\testData\\Setup.properties");
    p.load(fi);
    int colNum = -1;
    int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(p.getProperty("priceband"));
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
    for (int i = 0; i < getSheetColumns(p.getProperty("priceband")); i++) {
        row = sheet.getRow(0);
        cell = row.getCell(i);
        if (cell.getStringCellValue().equals(colName)) {
            colNum = cell.getColumnIndex();
            break;
        }
    }
    row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
    cell = row.getCell(colNum);
    return (cell.getNumericCellValue());
}

public void setCellData(int colNum, int rowNum, String str) throws IOException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\gpb7642\\Desktop\\PhAutomationFramework\\PhFramework\\src\\main\\java\\PhFramework\\testData\\Setup.properties");
    p.load(fi);
    int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(p.getProperty("priceband"));
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
    row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
    cell = row.createCell(colNum);
    cell.setCellValue(str);
    try {
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);

        try {
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

}
```

[image]

Comment: how is apache poi dependency defined in pom.xml?

Comment: I think you have missed entry of Apache-poi jar in your pom.xml

Comment: What is the output of `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: @Vladimir please find the POM tree code attatched to the original questions, please note I have also manually added Apache POI 3.15 via Eclipse

Comment: @Amit1011 please see above

Comment: @Florian Albrecht please see above

Comment: you have two versions of apache-poi - 3.15 and 3.15-beta2

Comment: @Phil_P85 adding jars via Eclipse is not the best choice when you have maven configuration in place - it messes things up

Comment: I don't see any output of `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: sorry @Florian Albrecht please find attatched

Answer (score 2):

`org.apache.poi.xssf...` is provided by `poi-ooxml` artifact, you need to add it to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

you also might want to remove `3.15-beta2` version of `poi` artifact

Comment: for some reason if I remove '3.15-beta2' my Excel methods no longer work, ok I will add the following dependency listed above and provide an update, thanks again

Comment: i have removed the manual dependencies, and also updated the POM with the above code and left only one version of POI 3.15. Even with these changes my test case executes however when reaching the method to Read from the excel sheet I get a 'null.pointer exception'. Please see my Excel Reader code above

Comment: its strange when I add poi3.15-beta2 manually its able to read excel data but then MVN test dosnt work, thanks for your help

Comment: it appears you need something in the 3.15-beta2 build which may be broken in the 3.15 build. You could try going back to 3.15-beta2, or you could try moving forward to 3.16-beta1. In any case remove the manual dependencies.